# update on datagridview does not update local db with update statement

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a login form that should be updating my local db with the current logged on users. On the form_load it pulls all users from the DB to a hidden datagridview via tableadapter and then refreshes it every 5 seconds via a timer.

on login it disables the timer, changes a single value on the datagridview and then runs the table adapter.update statement. On completion it enables the timer again to refresh the datagridview.

My problem is, at runtime for testing, the datagridview is visible and can see it changes the value for the user, but once it refreshes, its back to the old value. the code for the loginBtn_Click and Timer1_Tick is below :

```
Private Sub LoginBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click
    If PWTxt.Text = PW Then
        If DataGridView1.Item(4, temppos).Value = False Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            LoggedInID = tempID
            DataGridView1.Item(4, temppos).Value = True
            Me.LoginTableAdapter.Update(LoginDataSet)
            MenuForm.Show()
            MenuForm.Focus()
            Timer1.Enabled = True
        Else
            MsgBox(Trim(tempID) & " is currently logged in. Please contact your Systems Administrator.")
            End
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid Password")
        LoggedInID = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        Me.LoginTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginDataSet.Login)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to refresh. Error : " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any explanation or resolution would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the the Update method used by the DataSet. Make sure it is actually updating the columns you need to update.

Comment: this is my updatecommand generated by the wizard. `UPDATE       Login
SET                UserId = @UserId, Name = @Name, Surname = @Surname, PW = @PW, LoggedIn = @LoggedIn
WHERE        (UserId = @Original_UserId) AND (LoggedIn = @Original_LoggedIn)`